# Failed to compile HTML5 in libgdx (./gradlew html:superDev)

Tags: html, gradle, compilation

A week ago he compiled without problems and could test my project via web, but these days I've been testing and fault me:

The error is as follows:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':html:superDev'.

  > Process ' command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java' ' finished with non-zero exit value 1

BUILD FAILED

Comment: Please don't use images for text. Edit your question and copy and paste the text.